# Multi functional Standalone Editor for custom language

Tags: netbeans, editor, lexer, scintilla, geany

I am considered to generate **Editor** for my company language. It will be better if this editor will be *standalone*. I have limited time (2.5 week) and limited knowledge (3yrs of university). This language is does not look like any other language and designed for specific hardware. My editor must includes as much of below features as possible

```
    Syntax highlighting
    Indentation 
    Brace Matching 
    Code Folding 
    Error Parsing
    Reformatting 
    Snippets
```

I had some research with the following IDEs using below parser and lexer generators.

**1)NetBeans && JavaCC**

The problem about this is that

```
 *hard to make standalone
 *because syntax and semantic is too different that java like languages
  it  needs to change most of  Java.1.5.jj file.
```

**2)NetBeans and ANTLR**

```
 * hard to make standalone again
 * more time consuming because it makes me deal with the thing that already
   done . I have Language syntax and semantics i dont need to build it up 
   again just need to syntax defined language parser and lexer.
```

**3) Eclipse XTEXT**

```
 * it seems me even more time consuming and more labored than others
```

**4) Geany FILETYPES**

```
 * I used Geany Filetypes it was good in the beginning. I was able to 
   do snippets, syntax colorings but i could not code blocking 
   because my language does not use "{" and "}" instead use some keywords
   like  **end if** and **end for**
 * The second problem about this choice i must assign in filetype 
   configuration file: lexer_filetype and styling ,but as i mentioned 
   because distinctions with other language i must have its own 
   lexer_filetype and styling
```

**5) Geany and scintilla**

```
  * Could not find good tutorial about their cooperation.
```

Any kind of help, advice or suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: What to choose ? What is your suggestion for generating editor for custom language?

Comment: This question is to broad and mostly opinion based. There is no geneeral solution. Take your time and test them all or just try one and get around the issues you might have. There is no clear YES or NO or "Use this".

Comment: At least do you know any good tutorial where i can find geany and scintilla cooperation.

Comment: I assume you have already checked http://www.geany.org/manual/current/index.html Not sure what kind of documentation you are looking for.

Comment: This is what I suggest: Close this question and split it up.

Comment: Unfortunately their (both) documentations is not enough for learning and getting information how scintilla can work under control of  Geany IDE

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82057/discussion-between-frlan-and-mirmix).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my research i come up to this for the person in my situation  **NetBeans && JavaCC** is better solution than with **ANTLR** but it also needs tons of change and it is far away being standalone. The best among this that close to standalone and easy to manage in small amount of time and effort is the last one **Geany and scintilla**